# Python serial.write() does not send serial data to Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am writing a Python script, that sends a character to an Arduino and the Arduino prints the received character back. But in this case, the Arduino is always giving a garbage value. Also there is no error while executing the Python script.

I have checked multiple blogs, articles and tutorials and followed the exact steps, but I got no solution.

This is my Python script:

```py
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
ser.write('8')
read=ser.readline()
print(read)
```

This is the Arduino code:

```cpp
int temp;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  temp=5;
}

void loop() {
  temp=Serial.read();
  Serial.println(temp);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Arduino always prints -1 in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation on [`Serial.read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read):

> **Returns**
>
> the first byte of incoming serial data available (or -1 if no data is available) - *int*

So do as Ivan Sheigets suggested or

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("You sent: ");
}

void loop() {
  int temp=Serial.read();
  if(temp>=0)
    Serial.print((char)temp);
}
```

Make sure to cast the incoming value to char `(char)temp`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Serial.available()`.

```cpp
void loop() 
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      temp=Serial.read();
      Serial.print(" I received:");
      Serial.println(temp);
    }
}
```